# Opening Python IDLE from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-idle

Hi I have bought a Rasberry Pi with Python 3 on it. I can open the Python 3 shell and it works but I can't access an editor. How do I open a Python editor?

cheers

Comment: run `idle3` for `python3` and `idle` for `python2`

Comment: This answers given below, which I believe correct, should apply to many other Linux distribution also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the standard distribution of Python comes with IDLE, many Linux distributions do not include it. After you launch Python from command line, try the Python command,

```
>>> from idlelib import idle
```

That should start up IDLE with the same version of Python you started, regardless of how your symlinks are set up, if you have it installed for that Python version at all. If not, try installing IDLE with your package manager.

---

In case you are unfamiliar with IDLE, note that unless you open a file with it, IDLE starts with a Python shell window only. You can open a new IDLE editor window from the file menu of the IDLE shell window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2 type idle in a command window.

If you are using Python 3 type idle3 in a command window.

If you are using a GUI there should be shortcuts to IDLE and IDLE3 on screen.

Comment: Using a GUI pull down menu. The option in the menu says IDLE Python 3. The Python shell/kernel opens and works fine but not the editor.